# Анимация перехода между фрагментами

Tags: android, анимация, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

При переключении между фрагментами через DrawerLayout происходит плавная анимация смены фрагмента. Один пропадает, за ним появляется другой.

Но при использовании navController.navigate(....) анимации, как не бывало, топорно и некрасиво переключается. Подскажите как заставить анимацию срабатывать при вызове вручную.

```
  drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.


    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools,R.id.nav_send, R.id.app_bar_search)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();

    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawer,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    //noinspection deprecation
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

Answer (score 0):

В NavigationComponent все анимации прописываются в графе фрагментов. Например:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.wispapp.themovie.ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_main_to_details"
            app:destination="@id/movieDetailsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@animator/enter_out_right"
            app:exitAnim="@animator/exit_in_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@animator/enter_out_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@animator/exit_in_right" />

    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

И собственно когда вы вызываете новый фрагмент, вы указываете id action, вместо id фрагмента

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_main_to_details)
```